# Real network performance gain in Silverlight 5 compared to 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

In Silverlight 5's feature list we can see:

> Reduced network latency by using a background thread for networking.
>   This is helpful for scenarios that use client HTTP web requests.

I am wondering if anyone is aware of actual effect.

In which scenarios would that be noticable, did anyone run some thorough test? 
Which problem was this fix targeting to address?

**EDIT**: about close

Following reason

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific
>   expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments,
>   polling, or extended discussion.

is really weird reason to close this question. I didnt ask whether god exist, I asked about this update. Which is clearly technical, and quantifiable. I think someone around the world was likely to compare old and new network performance, and find a scenario where benefit can be seen clearly.

Also I believe this update was a result of someones request, which means someone had a SL4 scenario where performance wasn't enough, and such guys should be very aware of update resulting performance gain.

So what kind of solicit debate can happen here? Someone either knows, or he has no idea like the most people.

So I cast reopen and would like someone curious enough to answer sometime if he stumbles upon this question.

Comment: I haven't seen noticeable improvements, obviously because my app's performance is not network-bound, the actual use (automatic XML deserialization) of the downloaded data takes far more time than the network latency.

Comment: So the question you should ask yourself is: is your app suffering from network latency right now?

Comment: @jv42 the question I asked is the question I asked. Projecting your understanding of question on someone else is a little strange in this field of work. I thought maybe someone was curious enough and ran some test and knew actual numbers behind this update. I dont get the close at all, but whatever.

Comment: I was curious too, I provided my observations. But I'm worried about useless optimization too, and that's what I was trying to express. Sorry if you found it offensive.

Comment: BTW, in the close reason, there is 'polling', I guess that's the real close reason.